# I need to use mongodb native driver to find distinct ids ordered by a timestamp field

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using the nodejs mongodb native driver.  I am writing a chat program. I have a collection called dialog, that has sessionId and dateCreated (timestamp) fields.  I need a list of distinct sessionIds order by their last (max) dateCreated timestamp. I also need a limit of 20 records.

Here is what I have so far (obviously lacking the ordering):

```
db.collection('dialog').distinct('sessionId',
        function(err, users){
            if(users.length > 10){
                users = users.slice(0, 20);
            }
            console.log("users: " + users);


        });
```

Here are a couple documents.

```
{ 
  "sessionId" : 455206183, 
  "msg" : "hi what's up?", 
  "dateCreated" : ISODate("2015-02-05T20:17:55.418Z"), 
  "_id" : ObjectId("54d3cff30e3ddb6922fbc2bb") 
}, { 
  "sessionId" : 163220612, 
  "msg" : "yo", 
  "dateCreated" : ISODate("2015-02-05T20:18:00.434Z"), 
  "_id" : ObjectId("54d3cff80e3ddb6922fbc2bc") 
}
```

Comment: To do this you would need to do an aggregation call (as that's the only way of getting distinct results while sorting).  Could you post a reduced schema you are using?

Comment: I posted some documents.  I'm not sure what you mean by reduced schema.  My understanding is mongo is schemaless.

Comment: It technically is, but other libraries add schemas on top of it.  If you don't have a map of the data you're writing, you'll have a bad time.

Comment: Technically mongo prefers the term 'dynamic schema'... just splitting hairs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olli K got me headed in the right direction.  Doing the sort after the group by seems to work correctly.

```
db.collection('dialog').aggregate([
        {$group: {_id:"$sessionId", dateCreated: {$first: "$dateCreated"} }},
        {$sort: {"dateCreated":-1}},
        {$limit: 20}],
function(error, users){
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you'd probably need an aggregate to get the wanted results. Something like the below might work for you:

```
db.dialog.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "$dateCreated": -1, "$sessionId": 1 }},
    { $group: { _id: "$sessionId", dateCreated: {$first: "$dateCreated"} }},
    { $limit: 20 },
    { $project: { sessionId: 1, _id: 0 }}
]);
```

Here we first sort the collection by the `dateCreated` and `sessionId`, group them by the distinct id and pick the [$first](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) of the `dateCreated` (the newest), limit the results to 20 and return an array of objects each containing only the sessionId value.

Note that I didn't try this one out, so let me know if it works for you.

Comment: At first I get error: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.  When I remove $ from dateCreated and sessionId in the sort... I get 20 blank objects.